# Why are some SVGs not displayed properly in print composer?

Tags: qgis, svg, print-composer

I am having weird problem with adding .svg to qgis print composer. I have done some smaller symbols before in inkscape and they work - however the latest one displayed itself as huge black square.

I -did- find a very round about way of making it work, but I havent slightest idea why it works like this:   First I saved the .svg in Inkscape as pdf file, then used http://www.online-convert.com/ to convert the .pdf back to .svg ....and after this QGIS displays it fine in print composer.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? I have added the working and original not working .svg's as uploads, if someone wants to try it out.

http://speedy.sh/XGMWs/Svg-example.zip

Comment: is it a case that you just need to refresh the window for it to display. how does it look when you print of write to pdf?

Comment: @Jan: now, six and a half years later, I do come across the same issue. Have created my first svg in Inkscape. When adding it to my QGIS3.8 map as the [Single symbol], I see large black squares. When I choose [Drop Shadow] as a [Draw effect], they disappear on screen. But when I choose this situation as a [Layout], they come back. As well when I indeed finally [Export] it as a [Image] or [PDF]. Your first solution "object to path" within Inkscape didn't help. Therefore my question: did you come across a solution later on in your process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. It seems print composer does not like .svg's with text. I used inkscape "object to path" -function on both text's I had on the original .svg and now it displays properly. I also tested this on another .svg with text: It didnt display in print composer, until I used the same "Object to path" to change the texts into paths

Correction - I **thought**, I got it working, but now its broken again. Been 14h at work, Ill get back to this after weekend..

Comment: I am not sure what was the problem - I did they .svg again from the scratch in inkscape, turned the text into path and everything worked just fine.

Suppose I had some bit of text or something in the file and just didnt notice it?    Anyway, it seems the .svg's work in qgis as long as you dont have any text fields there.